# How to get answer from UISwitch which is in UIactionsheet

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, uiswitch

I am implementing Uiswitch inside my uiactionsheet, I've successfully placed it where i wanted to, but couldn't get the way to USE it. here's is my code:

```
switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
[mySheet addSubview:switchButton];
[mySheet showInView:self.view];

UILabel *instruction = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[instruction setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[instruction setText:@"Daily"];
[mySheet addSubview:instruction];

// get the dimension of the sheet to position the switch
CGSize parentSize  = mySheet.frame.size;
CGRect rect = switchButton.frame;
rect.origin.x = parentSize.width/2.0 - rect.size.width + 90;
rect.origin.y = parentSize.height - rect.size.height + 90 ;
switchButton.frame = rect;


//get the dimension of the sheet to possition the label
rect.origin.x = parentSize.width/2.0 - rect.size.width -20;
rect.origin.y = parentSize.height - rect.size.height + 90 ;
instruction.frame = rect;
```

I've initialized my switch button as an iboutlet. In actionsheet's function I'm trying to do this.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:        (NSInteger)buttonIndex{



    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {

            NSLog(@"Yes Button is working");
        }
            break;
         case 1:
        {

            if(switchButton.on){

            NSLog(@"IS on ?");
        }
          else {

         NSLog(@"Is off?");

         }
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

[image: It is all set]

**IMP I've also tried on more thing i had created "-(ibAction)funct" for it but when I did this I couldn't get the to link this with my switch **

Comment: Do you mean you can't use the switch (can't interact with it) or are not able to read the right values?

Comment: I cant read it , actually if u see my code in Uiactionsheet when iam trying catch through switch statement it never return any thing :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code will help

```
switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] init];

[switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: you should be able to read the input fine from the switch when using the [switch isOn] / on property. Something else might be wrong with your code, is the switch nil by any chance (at the point of reading)?

Answer (score 0):

Setting it as an IBOutlet won't do anything since you're creating the switch programmatically.  Really you should create your own UIViewController (and design it in Interface Builder) that you display modally rather than use a UIActionSheet which is designed for simple button selection.

However, if you do continue to use UIActionSheet, you could call 'addTarget' for the UISwitch when you create it to catch the events as the switch is changed.

Comment: So i should go for custom view's ?

Answer (score 0):

Also you could set a tag value (6 for example) for the UISwitch view, before adding the subview to the UIActionSheet. Then when the method `clickedButtonAtIndex` is fired you can check its value by using `[(UISwitch *)[actionSheet viewWithTag:6] isChecked]`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a BOOL flag which can set the value for the `UISwitch`

```
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
-(void)switchChanged{
    if(switchOn){
     switchOn=NO;
   }
   else {
     switch=YES;
   }
}
```

In `ActionSheet` you could check the flag `swithcOn`